# Windows 7 'netsh reset' without rebooting?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, reboot, network-adapter, netsh

Frequently we are required to reboot after installs or commands because specific services have to start or restart.  Is there some service I can restart to avoid rebooting the whole PC after "netsh reset"?

One of my users' Pulse Secure breaks often and rebooting fixes it sometimes, and sometimes it requires commands like "netsh reset" which require another reboot.  Reboots take 15 min because of other stuff loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the below as a batch script after running the [NETSH](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) commands to restart applicable services which may be affected by such a change.

You'll obviously want to test these services and confirm that it works for your need before running in production and to also potentially narrow down the number of services that actually need restarted with the specific commands you are using.

The source location has the full batch file you can download as well that also has other commands it runs to reset the network settings on Windows 7.

### [Complete Network Reset without needing a Restart](http://www.tweaking.com/forums/index.php?topic=1836.0)

```
@ECHO ON
ECHO Stopping Services...
net stop Mcx2Svc /y
net stop IPBusEnum /y
net stop HomeGroupProvider /y
net stop FDResPub /y
net stop fdPHost /y
net stop netprofm /y
net stop HomeGroupListener /y
net stop Browser /y
net stop LanmanServer /y
net stop WwanSvc /y
net stop NlaSvc /y
net stop WinHttpAutoProxySvc /y
net stop Dhcp /y
net stop Dnscache /y
net stop iphlpsvc /y
net stop SharedAccess /y
net stop Netman /y
net stop Browser /y
net stop Netlogon /y
net stop SessionEnv /y
net stop LanmanWorkstation /y
net stop nsi /y
net stop dot3svc /y
net stop Wlansvc /y
net stop EapHost /y
net stop KeyIso /y
net stop PolicyAgent /y
net stop lmhosts /y
net stop DPS /y
net stop EventSystem /y    

ECHO Starting Services...
net start EventSystem /y
net start DPS /y
net start lmhosts /y
net start PolicyAgent /y
net start KeyIso /y
net start EapHost /y
net start Wlansvc /y
net start dot3svc /y
net start nsi /y
net start LanmanWorkstation /y
net start SessionEnv /y
net start Netlogon /y
net start Browser /y
net start Netman /y
net start SharedAccess /y
net start iphlpsvc /y
net start Dnscache /y
net start Dhcp /y
net start WinHttpAutoProxySvc /y
net start NlaSvc /y
net start WwanSvc /y
net start LanmanServer /y
net start Browser /y
net start HomeGroupListener /y
net start netprofm /y
net start fdPHost /y
net start FDResPub /y
net start HomeGroupProvider /y
net start IPBusEnum /y
net start Mcx2Svc /y
```

<sub>[Source](http://www.tweaking.com/forums/index.php?topic=1836.0)</sub>