# Connection Reset on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome

So i left my computer on while i was asleep and i've done this multiple times in the past however this is the only time i encountered this problem.

I can't access anything except for a few websites on any browser.

I can access facebook and some other websites but most i can't. I just get that forever loading then connection was reset error.

So the first thing i thought was this should be a network problem. So i tried accessing my modem(192.168.1.1) same problem here,  connection was reset. can't access that. So i went onto my laptop and accessed it there and viola, i can access it there. The problem now is that i forgot the password since on my PC it has recorded the password(i don't get this btw, i thought its a cookie so i went on my chrome content settings and tried to find the cookie for 192.168.1.1(prolink adsl2 but couldnt find it there).

So after that i thought its probably a lan connection problem since i used wifi on my laptop. What other methods can i do to check? i suddenly thought of my WAMP server, so i tried accessing it on my PC and i can't. It just loads forever just like a connection was reset. then i tried it on my laptop and i can access it there. So i thought to isolate the problem more.

I disconnected my pc from the modem(lan) and i had no connection anymore right? so i tried again and i still can't access my localhost. I tried everything after this, i tried diagnosing my network, i ran CCleaner, i even tried using vpn(cyberghost). I'm also running a smart scan right now with ESET.

I don't know whats the problem its my first time encountering this and i can't find a solution on google since i don't know the specific problem.

Also i forgot to mention, i can access more sites if i type it on google search. Not the google search website but on the address bar it autoamtically searches on google if you don't put a .com at the end, still some sites like tomshardware i cant access. Sites like this stackoverflow i can access via doing that.

How do i even diagnose this kind of problem? i'm not as tech savvy as i really don't go out of my way to learn things, i just learn things when i encounter problems like this so the next time i'd have an idea.

EDIT: [Diagnosis and Troubleshoot results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6AgU.png)

The weird thing is, if i troubleshoot problem the network on the taskbar i get the first image above, if i directly go to my control panel then to the network adapter and directly diagnose it there i get the second result where it says the dns server is not responding.

Comment: Try to change your TCP/IP version 4 DNS settings to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for static DNS entries even if the I, subnet mask, and default gateway are set to DHCP and see what happens. If your DHCP is assigning out DNS otherwise and there are issues there then look over the DNS server or as the admins otherwise assign Google's DNS servers and use DNS externally. Look over my answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1187299/windows-7-cleanup-before-clonezilla-backup/1187334#1187334 and the admin elevated `IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS` and `NETSH INT IP RESET` and `NETSH WINSOCK RESET CATALOG` commands.

Comment: Furthermore, look over this solution in case you find it helpful with this problem: https://superuser.com/questions/1101038/windows-7-netsh-reset-without-rebooting/1101039#1101039

Comment: The problem is that i can't access my modem on this PC and i forgot the password. I tried finding the cookie for the modem site(192.168.1.1) but i couldn't find it on my chrome content settings.

I've only done the flush dns, let me do the other two.

Comment: i checked those links you have but i have no idea what they are tbh. It would have been fine if i had any background knowledge on them but i don't.

If i ran a windows update, would it help my problem? I stopped the windows update service running ever since i used this computer since i only have 4 gigs of ram and it eats atleast 2 gig of ram.